# What do the fields mean in the Azure Pricing REST API?

Tags: azure

I wish to use the Azure Pricing REST API. It lists several fields:

Filters are supported for the following fields:
armRegionName, Location, meterId, meterName, productid, skuId, productName, skuName,
serviceName, serviceId, serviceFamily, priceType, armSkuName

Where do I find information about what these fields mean?

Is there a way to find the productName, skuName, etc. of a virtual machine that I have created on Azure?

Comment: Are you checking the pricing of Azure function app?

Comment: Can you show the api reference you are based on?

Comment: @BowmanZhu I'm looking at this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/retail-prices/azure-retail-prices#api-property-details)

Answer (score 0):

> Where do I find information about what these fields mean?

The [Azure Retail Prices overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/retail-prices/azure-retail-prices) has a [description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/retail-prices/azure-retail-prices#api-property-details) of all the fields.

> Is there a way to find the productName, skuName, etc. of a virtual machine that I have created on Azure?

Locate the VM in the Azure portal and check Overview > Size. The size, e.g. Standard D2s v3, corresponds with the (arm)SkuName property returned by the API. Note that the portal doesn't include all the details, so you could try Azure CLI, e.g. `az resource show -g MyResourceGroup -n MyVm --resource-type "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"`, to display more details of the specified resource.

What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm still not able to see what the skuName, productName, productiid, meterid is on the portal

Answer (score 0):

From my best guess:

1. **armRegionName** - thats a id of region that you will use in ARM templates and Azure APis.
2. **Location** - thats a human readable name of region
3. **meterId** - Thats an id of how it will show up in your or consumption reports
4. **meterName** - same as above but human readable
5. **productid** - As I understand thats service + license. VM + Windows or + MSSQL
6. **productName** - same as above
7. **skuId**: Thats I believe and ID from Microsoft's license or contract entities
8. **skuName**: same as above
9. **serviceId**: Id of sub group of Service Family
10. **serviceName**: just a sub group of Service Family: Virtual Machines and etc
11. **serviceFamily**: just a group of services like Compute, Storage and etc
12. **priceType** - same as Type with values: DevTestConsumption, Reservation, Consumption
13. **armSkuName** - thats VM id that you will see in ARM templates or should use in Azure API calls.